# Why does a box appear when I try to make a window hole in a wall using Archimesh?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, archimesh-add-on

I get this weird thing when I set auto holes on the wall. It should boolean a hole for the window.

[image: Archimesh boolean problem]

Comment: Try selecting the item the hole is in (e.g., wall) then go into and out of edit mode (Tab key).  Sometimes this resets the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the settings for the "CTRL_Hole" object: if that object is renderable ("camera" icon in the last column not grayed out), you'l see it in the render. The hole for the window will be present, just hidden by the Ctrl_Hole object.

You could also try the other 'solver' option in the boolean modifier.

Answer (score 0):

My holes didn't work because I did't set wall thickness.

Comment: One sentence rarely does make a good answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I don't know what else to add. If you are trying to use auto holes you already know how to make walls and the thickness property is just right there.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I forgot to assign thickness to walls. Try that :) Also the auto holes function loves to randomly stopping working, but comes back if you just click it again ;)